# Which is the besy way to update a Django project from 1.25 to 1.4

Tags: django

I don't know what I was thinking and I don't have any kind of tests on this project. I want to upgrade it to 1.4 to be able to add to it all kind of different tests and have a more rigid project. What tips or recommendations can you guys give me?

Thanks.

Comment: Try with virtualenvs to isolate it!

Comment: @santiagobasulto who would be mad enough to develop with django without virtualenvs? ;)

Comment: hehe, you're right. It was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to read through the release notes for each release to try to identify any areas that have changed that might break your existing code. Find them here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/

Since you don't have any tests for your project you just have to roll up your sleeves and run full site tests where you run your app and try to test as many features you can to see if it is working as epxected.

I have just done the 1.1.1 to 1.4 upgrade (but I had some tests to help me) and it was not that bad.

There are 2 aspects of the upgrade. One is just to get your app to run on the new version and one is to change/update your code to utilize the new features in the 1.4 release. I would recommend that you first get it to work properly, release it and then refactor your code as you go along to use any new feature.

Comment: Do you think I should upgrade by steps, meaning, go 1.3 test the whole site, fix some code and then jump to 1.4?

Comment: I think it depends on how large your project is. I went directly from 1.1.1. to 1.4 and that worked for me. You will probably have to review your code base a bit so I think you can go for the 1.4 immediately.

Comment: It's quite a big project, but since I have to do a complete site funcionality test, I guess I should just jump to 1.4 and not test the site twice. Thanks